# Authenticate to GKE Rest API

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to query the GKE REST API with `Invoke-RestMethod` in Powershell. How do I authenticate? I tried with an API key passed as a header but that did not work. I keep getting the error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod: 
Line |
  10 |  … sresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $clustersuri -Headers $gkeheaders  …
     |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | {
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devco
nsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Any pointers are appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to access the Kube API server or just the GKE REST API (https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest)?

Comment: Just the GKE API. I've tried the authentication methods on there but always missing out on something

Comment: Hi, could you tell what exactly are you trying to request? Have you seen by any chance this documentation (example of many) that has a *Try this API* option where you can see what exactly is needed to be sent: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.clusters/get?apix=true?

Answer (score 0):

For the GKE REST API https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest, you have to provide an `api key` as a query parameter in your REST requests.

See the following documentation for creating and using api keys: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#using_an_api_key

Comment: Thanks, thinking the API key will expire pretty soon? I want something that would persist. Was looking at this here but not sure what step 6 is all about and what code should go in my Powershell script.
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/api-server-authentication#environments-without-gcloud

Comment: this documentation is for accessing the kubernetes API server, not the GKE REST API. If you cannot use an api key, you have to use OAUTH2. I think the simplest for Powershell will be to use a `Service Account`: see https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#httprest